# Openlitespeed as a WebSocket Proxy

Tags: socket, litespeed, socket.io

I am building web applications related to the socket.
And my application runs well without https, if it has https, it will not connect.

And as guidance on nginx must configure additional proxy.

But I do not know on openlitespeed configured in any way?

Here's how to configure on nginx, please help me configure on openlitespeed!

https://www.nginx.com/blog/nginx-nodejs-websockets-socketio/

```
server {
    server_name app.domain.com;
    location / {
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_pass http://socket_nodes;
    }
}

location /assets {
    alias /path/to/assets;
    access_log off;
    expires max;
}
```

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Check this [wiki](https://openlitespeed.org/mediawiki/index.php/OpenLiteSpeed_as_Reverse_Proxy_for_Rocket.Chat), it's made for rocketchat, but the websocket procedure is same.